# illegal reference to non-static member

Tags: c++, visual-c++

I am trying to refer to a cstring `mycustompath` from a different class from my current class.

```
CString test = CBar::mycustompath + _T("executables\\IECapt");
```

But I got this error instead:

> error C2597: illegal reference to non-static member 'CBar::mycustompath'  c:\work\b.cpp   14

How to fix this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This means that mycustompath is a property of a specific CBar object and not a property of the CBar class. You'll need to instantiate a CBar class

```
CBar* myBar = new CBar();
CString test = myBar->mycustompath + _T("executables\\IECapt");
```

or reference one you already have or, if mycustompath doesn't vary by CBar object, you can change it to static in the class:

```
class CBar
{
public:
    static CString mycustompath;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

This indicates that `CBar::mycustompath` is not a static member variable of `CBar`. You will have to create an instance of `CBar` to access it:

```
CBar bar;
CString test = bar.mycustompath + _T("executables\\IECapt");
```